# How to toggle color mode change on a Switch Chakra UI component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, chakra-ui

I'm trying to toggle different color modes with a `<Switch onChange={toggleColorMode}>`. However, it's not really changing colors after the switch component changes state. I'm new to using Chakra UI for react, and I followed the instructions in the docs for Color Mode https://chakra-ui.com/docs/features/color-mode.

I updated my theme config and I passed the `customTheme` to ChakraProvider component in main App component.

```
import { extendTheme,ThemeConfig } from "@chakra-ui/react";

const config : ThemeConfig = {
    initialColorMode:"light",
    useSystemColorMode:true,
}
const customTheme = extendTheme({
    fonts:{
        heading:"Spartan",
    },
    config
})


export default customTheme;
```

```
import * as React from "react"
import {
  ChakraProvider,
  Box,
  Text,
  FormControl,
  FormLabel,
  Switch,
  useColorMode,
  useColorModeValue
} from "@chakra-ui/react"
import "@fontsource/spartan/700.css"
import customTheme from "./theme"


// First Theme
const darkSaturatedBlue = {
  // main background
  mainBackgroundColor:"hsl(222, 26%, 31%)",
  // toggle background, keypad background
  toggleKeybadBackgroundColor:"hsl(223, 31%, 20%)",
  // screen background
  screenBackgroundColor:"hsl(224, 36%, 15%)",
  // Button digit colors
  buttonDigitColor:"hsl(221, 14%, 31%)",
}


export default function App(){
  const {toggleColorMode} = useColorMode();

  const bg = useColorModeValue("red.500",darkSaturatedBlue.mainBackgroundColor);
  const color = useColorModeValue("white","gray.800");

  
  return (
    <ChakraProvider theme={customTheme}>
    <Box bg={bg} h="100vh" w="100vw" color={color}>
      <Box mx="auto" w={["100%",375]}>
        {/* Main App Container */}
        .......
               <Box>
                <FormControl display="flex" alignItems="center">
                      <FormLabel htmlFor="theme-switch" mb="0" fontSize="9">
                        THEME
                      </FormLabel>
                      <Switch id="theme-switch" size="sm" onChange={toggleColorMode} />
                </FormControl>
              </Box>
       ......
      </Box>
    </Box>
  </ChakraProvider>
  );
}
```

The colors used are an example I set out initially to test the waters. Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. For some reason, using the hooks `useColorModeValue` and `useColorMode` in the `_app.js` don't change the colors accordingly to the setting of dark mode.

In the `App()` component, before the `return`, I tried using `const { colorMode } = useColorMode();` and the value of `colorMode` is `undefined`.

Comment: Can you try set use system color to false: useSystemColorMode:false

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, you can't change the color mode directly below the `ChakraProvider`, you have to do it in a component. For example this code would work:

```js
// index.js
import Page from "./app"
import { ChakraProvider } from "@chakra-ui/react"

export default function App () {
    return <ChakraProvider>
      <Page />
    </ChakraProvider>
}
```

```js
// app.js
import { Button, useColorMode } from "@chakra-ui/react"

export default function Page () {
 const { toggleColorMode } = useColorMode()

 return <Button>Toggle</Button>
}
```

You could also merge these files:

```js
// index.js
import { ChakraProvider, Button, useColorMode } from "@chakra-ui/react"

function Page () {
 const { toggleColorMode } = useColorMode()

 return <Button>Toggle</Button>
}

export default function App () {
    return <ChakraProvider>
      <Page />
    </ChakraProvider>
}
```

I'm not sure of the details behind this, but I've encountered this issue, and this does fix it.

Answer (score 0):

i've had the same problem. Just disable cache network in the debugging page seems work for me